# How to retrieve a previously declared variable with __COUNTER__ pasted inside its name in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I have the following problem:

```
#define CONCAT_(A,B) A ## B
#define CONCAT(A,B) CONCAT_(A,B)
#define CREATE_NAME(N) CONCAT(N, __COUNTER__)
```

If I wanted to retrieve a specific `variable##__COUNTER__` later in the code how can I achieve this? I only need to get the previous one, something like:

```
#define CONCAT_(A,B) A ## B
#define CONCAT(A,B) CONCAT_(A,B)
#define CREATE_NAME(N) CONCAT(N, __COUNTER__)
#define GET_NAME_PREV(N, VAL) CONCAT(N, VAL)

auto CREATE_NAME(v);
auto test_current_counter_value = GET_NAME_PREV(v, __COUNTER__ -1);
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is almost impossible to do simply, unless you are willing to introduce an external library for this purpose?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why this kind of preprocessor nonsense is a bad idea.  Surely you can implement this safely with a std::vector or a std::list.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes you are right but I need to be evaluated at compile time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`BOOST_PP_SUB`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/sub.html) macro from `boost` library can be evaluated and expanded to an identifier.

```cpp
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/sub.hpp>

#define CONCAT_(A,B) A ## B
#define CONCAT(A,B) CONCAT_(A,B)
#define CREATE_NAME(N) CONCAT(N, __COUNTER__)
#define GET_NAME_PREV(N) CONCAT(N, BOOST_PP_SUB(__COUNTER__, 1))

auto CREATE_NAME(v) = true;
auto test_current_counter_value = GET_NAME_PREV(v);
```

Try it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qjTabEe45).

Comment: Thank you very much for this!!
If I wrote:
`auto CREATE_NAME(a)  = true;
auto CREATE_NAME(a) = GET_NAME_PREV(a);`

the compiler returns the following error:
"a variable declared with an auto type specifier cannot appear in its own initializer".

Do you have any suggestion?

I am using Clang 12.0.0

Comment: @kmc It will be expanded to `auto a0 = true; auto a1 = a1 // a2 - 1`, try `#define GET_NAME_PREV_N(L, N) CONCAT(L, BOOST_PP_SUB(__COUNTER__, N))` \n `auto CREATE_NAME(a) = true; auto CREATE_NAME(a) = GET_NAME_PREV_N(a, 2);`

Comment: Thank you very much mate, it behaves as expected!